# How to add autoplay attribute in html5 video player

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add an attribute `autoplay` to a `<video></video>` element, when a specific target button is clicked.

HTML

```
<video controls>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I tried with jQuery:

```
$('.targetButton').on('click', function(){
  $('video').attr("autoplay"," ");
});
```

... but the video does not play. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I updated your question adding that you expect the video to start playing when the button is clicked, otherwise there is not really a question: your code successfully adds the attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Setting the autoplay flag is not enough to make the video play, you should call the load() method right after setting autoplay to true so that the video will reload and then play, since the flag is true.

```
$('video').autoplay = true;
$('video').load();
```

But why do this when you can actualy play the video with JS? Here's how to do it with jQuery:

```
$('video').play();
```

Comment: .play() doesn't work for me but your first suggest does

Answer (score 2):

try this

```js
var video = document.querySelector("#video"),
  button = document.querySelector("button");


button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  video.play()
    //video.setAttribute("autoplay","autoplay")// this will set the attribute but will not play 
}, false);
```

```html
<p>
  <button>playVideo</button>
</p>




<video id="video" controls="" preload="none" mediagroup="myVideoGroup" poster="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/poster.png">

  <source id="mp4" src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source id="webm" src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source id="ogv" src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg">

        <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the attribute with JavaScript but you need to add an ID to the video element:

HTML

```
<video id="myVideo" controls>
    ...
</video>
```

Then you can get the element and set the attribute like this:

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("myVideo").autoplay = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

To better handle your video it is better to use the html video tag:

```
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="exampleModal"
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn-close"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
        ></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
          <video
            id="myVideo"
            controls
          >
          <source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-secondary"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
        >
          Close
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this you can use the `play` and `pause` events in javascript:

```
  const myModalOpen = document.getElementById("exampleModal");
  exampleModal.addEventListener("shown.bs.modal", (event) => {
    console.log("Abierto y autoplay");
    const video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    video.play();
  });

  const myModalClose = document.getElementById("exampleModal");
  exampleModal.addEventListener("hidden.bs.modal", (event) => {
    console.log("Cerrado y stop");
    const video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    video.pause();
  });
```

With this it will work

Answer (score -1):

> use video controls: autoplay

```
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

`also you can include`- Play,
Pause,
Seeking,
Volume,
Fullscreen toggle,
Captions/Subtitles (when available),
Track (when available)